# Unable to use custom taxonomy with front end post form

Tags: plugins

I have a front-end posting form configured for a custom post type. By using the form I am able to send the title, content, and image attachments without a hitch, but my custom taxonomy selection doesn't register. I've patched this functionality using various bits of code I have found and I'm not sure exactly what I screwed up.

add-new-listing.php

```
if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) &&  $_POST['action'] == "new_post") {

    // Do some minor form validation to make sure there is content
    if (isset ($_POST['title'])) {
        $title =  $_POST['title'];
    } else {
        echo 'Please enter the listing name';
    }
    if (isset ($_POST['description'])) {
        $description = $_POST['description'];
    } else {
        echo 'Please enter a description';
    }

    $tags = $_POST['post_tags'];

    // ADD THE FORM INPUT TO $new_post ARRAY
    $new_post = array(
    'post_title'    =>  $title,
    'post_content'  =>  $description,
    'post_category' =>  array($_POST['booru_locations']),  // Usable for custom taxonomies too
    'post_image'    => $newupload,
    'post_status'   =>  'publish',           // Choose: publish, preview, future, draft, etc.
    'post_type' =>  'booru_directory'  //'post',page' or use a custom post type if you want to
    );

    //SAVE THE POST
    $pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);


    //REDIRECT TO THE NEW POST ON SAVE
    $link = get_permalink( $pid );
    wp_redirect( $link );

//INSERT OUR MEDIA ATTACHMENTS
if ($_FILES) {
foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
$newupload = insert_attachment($file,$pid);
// $newupload returns the attachment id of the file that
// was just uploaded. Do whatever you want with that now.
}

} // END THE IF STATEMENT FOR FILES

} // END THE IF STATEMENT THAT STARTED THE WHOLE FORM

//POST THE POST YO
do_action('wp_insert_post', 'wp_insert_post');
```

functions.php

```
$labels = array(
    'name'                          => 'Locations',
    'singular_name'                 => 'Location',
    'search_items'                  => 'Search Locations',
    'popular_items'                 => 'Popular Locations',
    'all_items'                     => 'All Locations',
    'parent_item'                   => 'Parent Location',
    'edit_item'                     => 'Edit Location',
    'update_item'                   => 'Update Location',
    'add_new_item'                  => 'Add New Location',
    'new_item_name'                 => 'New Location',
    'separate_items_with_commas'    => 'Separate Locations with commas',
    'add_or_remove_items'           => 'Add or remove Location',
    'choose_from_most_used'         => 'Choose from most used Locations'
    );

$args = array(
    'label'                         => 'Locations',
    'labels'                        => $labels,
    'public'                        => true,
    'hierarchical'                  => true,
    'show_ui'                       => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'             => true,
    'args'                          => array( 'orderby' => 'term_order' ),
    'rewrite'                       => array( 'slug' => 'place', 'with_front' => false ),
    'query_var'                     => true
);

register_taxonomy( 'booru_locations', 'booru_directory', $args );


// Add new taxonomy, NOT hierarchical (like tags)
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'Services', 'Service Type' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Service', 'Service' ),
        'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Services' ),
        'popular_items' => __( 'Popular Services' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All Services' ),
        'parent_item' => null,
        'parent_item_colon' => null,
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Services' ),
        'update_item' => __( 'Update Service' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Service' ),
        'new_item_name' => __( 'New Service' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate Services With Commas' ),
        'add_or_remove_items' => __( 'Add or Remove Services' ),
        'choose_from_most_used' => __( 'Choose From Most Used Services' )
    );

register_taxonomy( 'services', 'booru_directory', array(
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'labels' => $labels, /* NOTICE: the $labels variable here */
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'services' ),
    ));




register_post_type( 'booru_directory',
    array(
        'labels'                => array(
            'name'              => __( 'Directory' ),
            'singular_name'     => __( 'Listing' )
            ),
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' ),
        'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => 'directory', 'with_front' => false ),
        'has_archive'           => true
    )
);
```

Comment: Is `$_POST['booru_locations']` a category id, or is a category name?

Comment: it's a category id

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Codex back for [`wp_insert_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post). I've not checked, but I do not think this is correct:

```
 'post_category' =>  array($_POST['booru_locations']),  // Usable for custom taxonomies too
```

The array passed to `wp_insert_post`, however can contain a `tax_input` key, whose value is an array of arrays:

```
 'tax_input' =>array( 'booru_locations' => array( 'term', 'term2', 'term3' ) )
```

The value for 'booru_locations' must an array of strings (for term slugs) or integers (for term IDs). If you are using term IDs you *must* make sure they are integers by casting them as such.

---

So `$_POST['booru_locations']` contains a term ID for the taxonomy 'booru_locations'. First, make sure its an integer (not a string representation of) and create an array of IDs (in this case there will be only one):

```
 $location_id = intval($_POST['booru_locations']);
 $locations = (!empty($location_id) ? array($location_id) : array());
```

So `$locations` an array of integers (term IDs). We can then add this to the `$new_post` array

```
// ADD THE FORM INPUT TO $new_post ARRAY
$new_post = array(
'post_title'    =>  $title,
'post_content'  =>  $description,
'post_image'    => $newupload,
'post_status'   =>  'publish',  
'post_type' =>  'booru_directory',
'tax_input' =>  array('booru_locations'=>$locations),
);
```

Comment: I don't understand. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Certainly, see updated answer with example

Comment: Where am I supposed to put `$location_id = intval($_POST['booru_locations']);
 $locations = (!empty($location_id) : array($location_id) ? array());`

Comment: Same place you put `$tags = $_POST['post_tags'];`

Comment: I thought so, but I tried that, I got this message `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in /home/cbooru/public_html/wp-content/themes/camerabooru_theme/add-new-listing.php on line 23`

Comment: oops, syntax error. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I tried again and there were no errors this time, but it still didn't apply the custom category

Comment: mmm... seems ok. May be try manually giving a value, e.g. `$locations=array(5)` where 5 is the ID of your custom taxonomy term. Also try displaying what you are receiving in `$_POST` with `wp_die` and `var_dump`. Apart from that I can't really help, looks to be the correct usage of `wp_insert_post`